# Using overridden class constants in class methods

Tags: ruby

To override class constants in a subclass one can do:

```
class Foo
  CONST = [:foo, :baz]

  def self.const
    self::CONST
  end

end

class Bar < Foo
  CONST = [:foo, :bar]
end

print Foo.const # [:foo, :baz]
print Bar.const # [:foo, :bar]
```

This works as expected. The problem is when I try to call it from a class method, e.g when using `define_method`:

```
class Foo
  CONST = [:foo, :baz]

  def self.const
    self::CONST
  end

  self.const.each do |c|
    define_method("#{c}?") {
      "#{c} exists"
    }
  end
end


foo = Foo.new
print foo.baz? # baz exists.

bar = Bar.new
print bar.bar? # undefined method `bar?'
```

How would one go about overriding the class constant so the right method `bar?` will get defined in this case, without having to duplicate the code in the subclass? Is there a DRY way of doing this without having to use class variables instead of class constants?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. Aren't you doing it without duplicating the code in the subclass?

Comment: @sawa: Yes, but it's not working :)

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: @sawa: `undefined method bar?`

Comment: You don't want that?

Comment: @sawa: No. I want to override the class constant so the base class defines the methods `foo?` and `bar?`

Comment: You have to write what you expect. You only gave what you got. It is not clear.

Comment: I assume you want to add no code to `Bar`. The problem is that `CONST = [:foo, :bar]` in `Bar` cannot be accessed by `Foo` until the class `Bar` is constructed. If, for example, you included the callback `def self.inherited(subclass)...end` in `Foo`, that method is executed right after the line `class Bar < Foo` is parsed, before  Ruby gets to `CONST = [:foo, :bar]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: What do you suggest I do with `self.inherited(subclass)`. Put the define method in class method and call that from there? Can you make your comment into an answer?

Comment: No, I'm saying the `inherited` callback won't help here. I suspect you cannot do what you want to do.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I suspect that too. What would you do in this case?

Comment: Add code to `Bar (which is the answer to a different question)`! :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: You would add the `define_method` to Bar you mean?

Comment: To `Foo`, add `def self.make_methods; const.each { |c| define_method("#{c}?") { "#{c} exists" } }; end; make_methods`. To `Bar`, after `CONST = [:foo, :bar]`, add `make_methods`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because define_method is running in lexical scope, i.e. it's inline in the body of the Foo class definition so there is nothing to cause it to run in Bar.

```
class Foo
  CONST = [:foo, :baz]

  def self.define_const_methods(const)
    const.each do |c|
      define_method("#{c}?") { "#{c} exists" }
    end
  end

  define_const_methods(CONST)
end

class Bar < Foo
  CONST = [:foo, :bar]
  define_const_methods(CONST)
end
```

That should do the trick. So you call define_const_methods at the end of the Foo class in it's lexical scope. And you also call it on any class that inherits from it. The inheriting class should find it's own version of that constant.

But this is pretty ugly, so you could dispense with the constants altogether and just use the define_const_methods to define them. Just like ActiveRecord does when it defines the association methods (has_one, has_many etc). So then you can whittle it down to;

```
class Foo
  def self.define_my_methods(meths)
    meths.each do |c|
      define_method("#{c}?") { "#{c} exists" }
    end
  end

  define_my_methods [:foo, :baz]
end

class Bar < Foo
  define_my_methods [:foo, :bar]
end
```

Comment: I had to do `self::CONST.each`. Also, it works without the `self.inherited` method. Isn't there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Have you tested? This doesn't work for the reason I gave in my comments. Dan, if you are testing this in IRB, you must reload IRB each time. Otherwise, you may run this when `Bar` is already defined, in which case it will appear to work fine.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I'm not. I am running it as a file from command line. But this is not the solution I was looking for. Should I just go for a class variable instead?

Comment: @dan-klasson yeah, inherited was a bit of a test. Coz the constants are all lexical I wanted to see where inherited actually gets called. I just saved my final edit. Which in summary is don't use constant.

Comment: @james2m: Now that is a solution I like. I'm totally stealing that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you'll not get the solution you were looking for as constants are defined lexically. Any time you define a subclass the constant being referenced will be the one from the parent class until Ruby has parsed the one in the body of the subclass.

Comment: Dan, you asked a question that I thought was pretty clear. That question has not been answered. If you want to ask a different question, that's fine, but SO questions are not intended to be a starting point for a general discussion.

Comment: James, I said that in a comment that I posted much earlier. It's precisely why your initial solution (since removed) won't work. Your last solution is a straightforward way of getting the task done, but it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: But it does work: http://dpaste.com/2QQAWRF . And true that it technically does not answer the original question, but I did ask for an alternative way to do it, hence the accepted answer. Also, if I didn't ask this specifical question it would have been too vague, and it would not be useful to people who'll have the same issue in the future.

Comment: Dan, James' initial solution, which did not modify `Bar`, was incorrect (see edit history). The code at the link you gave is essentially the same as what I suggested in an earlier comment. btw, you don't need `self::` or any of the `self.`s except for the one in `self.define_const_methods`.